# What is hash table ? what are the use of hash table in sql? how to create hash table in SQL?

Tags: sql-server

I have attempted SQL interview in last week and get new question
what are the use of hash table in SQL?
how to create hash table in SQL?

Comment: Never heard of Hash Table atleast in SQL Server. There is a Hash Index but that is not what you are asking.

Comment: Maybe, `HASH JOIN`...? For this physical operation `SQL Server` build a hash table

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server creates hash tables internally if it needs to. It is not a structure you can build like an index or so.
For example SQL Server uses hash tables for a hash join.

Answer (score 1):

Hash tables are tables that you can create on the fly. You create a hash table with syntax like this:

```
select * into #tableA from customerTable
```

The beauty of a hash table is that it exists only for your current connection. It is not accessible for someone connecting to your database from another connection. In fact it wont even be accessible if you try to access it from another window in your SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Using an HashTable you can store temporary data.
The Hash table are like Key/Value pair.

For more information see [#Table](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42553/Quick-Overview-Temporary-Tables-in-SQL-Server)

Comment: The question is about hash tables, not temp tables.

Comment: Hash table are one the form of temp table